# Let $a<b$ and $a,b\in\Bbb R$. Then there is $c$ such that $a<c<b$ and that $c$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $a<b$ and $a,b\in\Bbb R$. Then there is $c\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ such that $a<c<b$.

---

**My attempt:**

1. $a+b$ is irrational

Let $c:=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$

2. $a+b$ is rational

Let $x:=\dfrac{a+b}{\sqrt 2}$. Then $x$ is irrational.

- $a<x<b$

Let $c:=x$

- $b\le x$

Then $x-b<x-a$. Take $x'\in (x-b,x-a)$ such that $x'$ is rational.

Then $a<x-x'<b$ where $x-x'$ is irrational.

Let $c:=x-x'$.

- $x\le a$

Then $a-x<b-x$. Take $x'\in (a-x,b-x)$ such that $x'$ is rational.

Then $a<x+x'<b$ where $x+x'$ is irrational.

Let $c:=x+x'$.

---

My proof is quite short. I'm worried if it's sloppy and contains mistakes. Please help me verify it!

Comment: $\frac{a+b}{\sqrt2}$ isn't always less than $b$

Comment: Is $\frac{a+b}{\sqrt2}$ between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Oh that's my mistake. Let me fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: I have fixed it. Please check it out!

Comment: You just need to know that there is some irrational number. A concrete example is $\sqrt{2}$. For your second case when $(a+b) /2$ is rational, just choose positive integer $n$ such that $n(b-a) / 2>\sqrt{2}$ and then $x=\dfrac{a+b} {2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ is irrational and $a<x<b$.

Comment: "Take $x'\in(x−b,x−a)$ such that $x'$ is rational": how do you know there exists such an $x'$? Proving this looks just as hard as proving the initial statement!

Comment: Hi @TonyK! Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ :)

Comment: @Akira: OK, so now I present the proof of your original statement: Such a $c$ exists because $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ :)

Comment: Hi @TonyK! I'm actually not joking about that :) I've actually learned the property that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ when constructing $\Bbb R$ by Dedekind cuts. *Proving $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$* is an exercise at the end of chapter. And I'm doing it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following two sequences. $$ \{1/n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$ and $$ \{\sqrt 2/n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$

The first one, approaches $0$ with rational terms and the second one  approaches $0$ with irrational terms.

Pick a natural number n, such that $1/n$ and ${\sqrt 2}/n$ are both less than $b-a$

If $a$ is rational then $a+{\sqrt 2}/n$ is irrational and it is in the interval $(a,b)$

If $a$ is irrational then $a+{1}/n$ is irrational and it is in the interval $(a,b)$

Comment: Your approach is very simple, straightforward, and creative.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would prove it.  Suppose the interval $(a,b)$ has only rational numbers. Then, we know that $\frac{b-a}2$ must be rational since $$b-\frac{b-a}2 = \frac{a+b}2\in(a,b)$$ So, $b-a$ is rational.

However, we know that for all $x\in\mathbb R$, there exists $y\in[a,b),\;q\in\mathbb Z$ such that $x = y + q\cdot(b-a)$. This implies that the only irrational numbers are those of the form $a+q\cdot(b-a)$ -- since all $y\in(a,b)$ is rational -- which there are only a countable number of. This is a contradiction, since there are an uncountable number of irrationals.

Comment: I got your proof and it's clearly creative. I have fixed mine too. Could you please have a check on my proof?

Comment: Why would $(b-a) $ be rational? Your assumption that $(a, b) $ consists of rationals only implies that $(a+b) /2$ is rational. From here it simply does not follow that $(b-a) /2$ is rational.

Answer (score 1):

If $a, b$ both are rationals then, $\frac{b+a}{2}$ is rational. Then, lets pick $c= \frac{b+a}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2\sqrt{2}}$

If $a$ is rational, and $b$ is irrational, we take $c=\frac{b+a}{2}$

If $a, b$ are irrational:

$\frac{a+b}{2}$ is irrational then pick it as $c$.

Else we pick, $c=\frac{b+a}{2}+ (b-\frac{b+a}{2})/2$. $(b-\frac{b+a}{2})$ is irrational.

Comment: Who downvoted this? And why?